How do I paint and sculpt with a ''Connected only'' brush? Like edit mode has

So instead of weight painting in a 3d sphere, which also catched onto close geometry, painting in a connected only manner, that only edit mode has as far as I know.
If this logic exists for edit mode, it should also be able to work for weight and sculpt mode no?

No, this logic does not exist for Weight Paint. In Edit Mode, you have selected something - that is a very distinct part of the geometry, and Blender can evaluate what is connected to this selection and how far Proportional Editing should be affecting the connected mesh by the given radius of influence.
But in Weight Paint mode you have a brush with a certain size which influences where you paint. But when this size overlays vertices in the background, how should Blender determine that it is not the part lying further back which you want to paint, although you move the brush over it?
What you can do is mask areas you want to paint on. For example, you can select some faces in Edit Mode:

Then in Weight Paint, next to the mode selection menu there are buttons which let you enable paint masking by selected faces or vertices in Edit Mode:


Yes I was afraid It's not possible right now. I'll use masks then.
I'll continue looking into it since it should be possible.
In edit mode It's possible because you have a vert selected, but in sculpt mode it shows what vert you're cursor is nearest with the little dot, so by using that constantly updated point/vert it should be possible to draw a radial gradient from each point it passes, thus painting.

@Oenkel Yeah well, probably you should suggest that to the Blender developers and maybe this will change one day. I do not know if many people request that... as I personally see it, one of the reasons for proportional editing is that you can move, rotate, scale etc. with a falloff - which is not possible with selected vertices and no proportional editing. And you limit this influence by the size of the circle. In Weight Painting brushes usually have a falloff and you can customize it - no need for proportional editing there. And masking stops you from painting which should not be painted.
